# How to concat string with For Varible Vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 16 items named q1,q2,q3,...,q16 and txt_q1,txt_q2,...,txt_q16
And I need to check each one, so I have a for and inside I have the If like this:

```
For Cnt AS Integer = 1 To 16 Step 1
   If("q"&cnt = "") Then
      "txt_q"&cnt.Style.Add("color","blue")
      ....
      ..
   End If
End For
```

The idea is check al items with a For to avoid the 16 Ifs, but I have a syntax error.
What can I do?

the txt_q1,txt_q2... are IDs for asp:labels, and I have a radiobuttonList, so I get the radiobutton text and I set q1, q2, q3... to the corresponding radiobuttonlist. So I want to check if there is a radiobuttonlist that is not checked, if not I change the color to blue to the asp:label. So I want to avoid making 16 ifs for each radiobuttonlist and make it with a For, because the only thing that change in the variables is the number is the same "q" and the same "txt_q" so I want to add the number to "q" or "txt_q" to make it one variable called q1 or txt_q1 that already exist and that way acces to the txt_q1.Style.Add() and change the color of that label.

Thank You

Comment: what are these `items`?  Sort of looks like you are trying to use strings as object references.

Comment: are variables As strings from radiobuttons text

Comment: still not clear, but `"txt_q"&cnt.Style.Add...` is almost certainly never going to work.  if you are trying to create a control reference, use the name with `Me.Controls()`

Comment: i think it is better to use array(16) instead for 16 variables, you can't check like `"q"&1` if `q1` is a variable

Comment: mmm, the idea of concatening "txt_q"&cnt.Style.Add() is be equal to txt_q1.Style.Add(),txt_q2.Style.Add()...etc

Comment: just use your concat as the key in `Me.Controls`  if `txt...` is an object, you cannot create *object references* on the fly

Comment: no its not the same thing, please check my question again that I have edited, I hope that give you more information about what I want to do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just for your understanding:

When you write `"txt_q"&cnt`, you are creating a new string literal which holds e.g. `"txt_q1"`, `"txt_q2"`, etc. This resembles the name of the variables, but is really something completely different. The name of the variable is just for you to write in code. The value of the variable is a reference to the control object. What you need is to obtain the reference to the controls. This can be done on several ways, one is to use the [FindControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
For Cnt AS Integer = 1 To 16 Step 1
   Dim c = FindControl("q" & cnt) 'pass in the ID here, you will get a reference
   'you can use c to access the properties e.g. c.Style
End For
```

Again, just to clarify

```
c.Style 'c is a variable holding a reference to the control
"c".Style ' "c" is a simple string
```